# How can I get to the particular element in the list which is internal list of other list in Java?

Tags: java, list, get

If I declare something like this:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
list.get(0).get(1);//error
```

Now I have got "list in list" and I would like to get to the second element of the internal list of the first list. How can I do that? This doesn't work:

```
list.get(0).get(1);//error
```

Comment: You would have to add a cast to it. `((ArrayList<String)list.get(0)).get(1);`

Comment: Why a `List<Object>` and not a `List<List<String>>` to start with?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the returned object from `list` to `ArrayList`, since you declared your list with `Object` type > `List<Object>`

So try to change your code to something like:

```
((ArrayList<String>) list.get(0)).get(1);
```

Or change the declaration of your list like:

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

Then your code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Why not declare this properly ?

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

i.e. you declare this as a list of lists, and the compiler knows that `list.get(0)` will give you a list.